# Not able to make post request to native domain from chrome extension

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Description - I have a website www.robustest.com which bind with http://robustestom.appspot.com.

When I am tying to make post request to /user/signup (robustest) from a chrome extension Postman I am getting following error

```
Request URL:http://robustest.com/user/signup
Request Method:POST
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently

**Response Header -**
Alternate-Protocol:80:quic
Content-Length:233
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 30 Dec 2013 03:43:43 GMT
Location:http://www.robustest.com/user/signup
Server:ghs
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

But its working as expected when I am firing against http://robustestom.appspot.com/user/signup.

Why We need - We are making an extension  and there we need post request against our doamin.

Debugging - I might be wrong but it seems , all post request are redirecting to their counter part 'GET' because of origin is  not 'robustest.com' but its a 'chrome extension'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 301 is redirecting from robustest.com to www.robustest.com. Add the www to the domain the extension is making requests to and the 301 error should go away.

Comment: I am getting 301 not 302

Comment: Both are redirect codes, 301 is just permanent versus 302 which is temporary. Because the naked domain is never the location that will send the response from app engine, it's giving you a permanent redirect.